# comparing the java current timestamp againt column in oracle db

Tags: java, oracle11g

I have column in oracle DB which is stored values in this format

```
'20-DEC-2022 02.04.19.2424 PM'
'02-DEC-2022 03.14.19.1524 AM'
'02-NOV-2022 11.14.19.1524 PM'
'02-MAY-2022 08.14.19.1524 AM'
```

From Java, I need to compare with system time against emp_updt_timestmp column. Does below query fetch correct results?

I will pass the current time from java['20-12-2022 04.02.12 PM']. Do I need to pass in this format only from Java?

```
.select * from emp where emp_updt_timestmp >= to_timestamp('20-12-2022 04.02.12 PM','dd-mm-yyyy hh.mi.ss AM')
```

Comment: *Exactly* what is the data type of the column? Show the `CREATE TABLE` code.

Comment: You should be using a column of an appropriate date-time type to store date-time data. If so, there is no "format", as such stored values are not text.

Comment: emp_updt_timestmp is a TIMESTAMP data type

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is the **wrong data type** to use for tracking the moment a row was inserted/updated. You should be using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. This has been discussed extensively on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
select *
from   emp
where  emp_updt_timestmp >= TIMESTAMP '2022-12-20 16:02:12'
```

or strings in whatever format you want (so long as the format model matches the format of the string):

```sql
select *
from   emp
where  emp_updt_timestmp >= to_timestamp('20-12-2022 04.02.12 PM','dd-mm-yyyy hh.mi.ss AM')
```

or, for example, an ISO8601 format:

```sql
select *
from   emp
where  emp_updt_timestmp >= to_timestamp('2022-12-20T16:02:12','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

or, better, you can use a prepared statement and bind variables:

```sql
select *
from   emp
where  emp_updt_timestmp >= ?
```

and then in your Java code you can use [`PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(java.sql.Timestamp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,%20java.sql.Timestamp)) or [`oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement.setTIMESTAMP(oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setTIMESTAMP_int__oracle_sql_TIMESTAMP_) to bind the value to it.